# Add WhatsApp stickers to WhatsApp web / desktop versions

Tags: windows, browser, android, web, whatsapp

How can I add my own stickers to WhatsApp desktop / web versions?

I've got other 3rd party stickers installed and they only show up on my phone. When I install one of the sticker packs provided by WhatsApp itself they show up fine in all versions of WhatsApp.

So is there an option to add your own stickers to WhatsApp web similar to when you install a pack from the app itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that it's not currently supported. You may consider tracking it here: https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/issues/210